# Yii2-display name instead of id in read-only text box

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have two textboxes in my `create form`. Both have user id's in it. Now I want to display the `username` of the user.

I have a form in which I select an `imsi` number. Right after selecting it the user to whom the `sim` was issued and to whom the sim is to be returned will be shown. Below is my code

**View**

```
  <?= $form->field($model, 'imsi')->hiddenInput()->label(false)?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'return_by')->textInput(\app\models\User::toArrayList()) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'return_to')->textInput(\app\models\User::toArrayList()) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'return_reason')->dropDownList(\common\models\SimReturn::simreturnReason()) ?>
```

**JQuery**

```
jQuery('#the-sim-id').on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum) {             
        var html = '<div class="selected-imsi"><input type="hidden" name="selected_imsi[]" value="'+datum.id+'" />'+datum.imsi+'<a onclick="$(this).closest(\'.selected-imsi\').remove()">X</a></div>';
        //alert(datum.sim_id); 
        $('#selected_imsi_container').append(html);
         $('#simreturn-imsi').append(datum.imsi);
         $('#the-sim-id').typeahead('val','');
         $('#simreturn-return_by').val(datum.issued_to);
         $('#simreturn-return_to').val(datum.created_by);            
     });
```

The function `toArrayList()` is below

```
 public static function toArrayList(){
    if(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role==Roles::ROLE_TEAM_LEAD && Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id != ''){
        return ArrayHelper::map(User::find()
            ->where(['group_id'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id])
            ->andWhere('id!='. Yii::$app->user->id)
            ->andWhere('user_role!=2')
            ->andWhere('user_role=4')
            ->orWhere('user_role=3')
            ->all(), 'id', function ($model,$defaultValue){
            return $model['username'].' - '.Roles::idToName($model['user_role']);
        });
    }
   else if(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role==Roles::ROLE_SIM_MANAGER)
    {
        return ArrayHelper::map(User::find()
            //->where(['group_id'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id])
            ->andWhere('id!='. Yii::$app->user->id)
            ->andWhere('user_role!=2')
            ->andWhere('user_role=7')
            ->orWhere('user_role=8')
            ->orWhere('user_role=6')
            ->all(),'id',function ($model,$defaultValue){
            return $model['username'].' - '.Roles::idToName($model['user_role']);
        });

    }
    else if(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role ==Roles::ROLE_PRODUCTION_MANAGER)
    {
       return ArrayHelper::map(User::find()
              ->andWhere('id!='.Yii::$app->user->id)
              ->andWhere('user_role!=2')
              ->andWhere('user_role!=3')
              ->andWhere('user_role!=4')
              ->andWhere('user_role!=5')
              ->andWhere('user_role!=6')
              ->andWhere('user_role!=1')
              ->andWhere('user_role!=8')
              ->orWhere('user_role=7')
              ->all(),'id',function ($model,$defaultValue){
           return $model['username'].' - '.Roles::idToName($model['user_role']);
       });
    }
    return ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->where(['user_type'=>'user'])->andWhere('user_role!=2')->all(),'id',function ($model,$defaultValue){
        return $model['username'].' - '.Roles::idToName($model['user_role']);
    });
}
```

The above function gives me the `username-role_name`

Now when I open the form and selects an `imsi` number, then in textboxes I am only seeing the id's of the users and not their name.

[image]

I have two issues

1. How to display the username instead of id
2. How can I make the textbox read-only? as I have already tried `->textInput(\app\models\User::toArrayList(),['readonly'=>'readonly'])`

But it says

> Method call uses 2 parameters, but signature uses 1 parameters

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- About `Arrayhelper::map()`: Builds a map (key-value pairs) from a multidimensional array or an array of objects.The `$from` and `$to` parameters specify the `key` names or `property` names to set up the map. Optionally, one can further group the map according to a grouping field `$group`.

  So you see the second parameter you are passing is the callback

  ```
  function ($model,$defaultValue){
      return $model['username'].' - '.Roles::idToName($model['user_role']);
  }
  ```

  which returns **`$model['username'].' - '.Roles::idToName($model['user_role']);`** and map function tries to get the column name `username-roll_name` from the array which is obviously not any column name, so first of all change it to a valid column name but you want to display the label as `username-rollname`, rather than providing the callback for the `keyname` in `ArrayHelper` you should select the columns as alias using `CONCAT` in your `SQL` and then provide that alias to the `map()` function second parameter to display the label as `username-roll_name`.
- The second issue is obvious you are passing the second parameter to the `textInput()` which isn't there, according to the [**`docs`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#textInput()-detail) this method will generate the name and value tag attributes automatically for the model attribute unless they are explicitly specified in `$options`.

  You can use the `inputOptions` option in the `field()` for `['readonly'=>'readonly']`, should be passed in the `field` like  `$form->field($model, 'return_by',['inputOptions'=>['readonly'=>'readonly']])->textInput(\app\models\User::toArrayList())`

Hope it helps you out

Comment: @MrOmer, the term `username-roll_name` is not a field name. The `return $model['username'].' - '.Roles::idToName($model['user_role']);` do return me the correct username and the roll name, like `imran-Production Manager`.

Comment: `\app\models\User::toArrayList()` I am using it in a dropdown and it's working perfectly

Comment: it would be returning the correct name from the callback but the `map()` function would search that term `imran-Production Manager`  as a `column` name which is nowhere and that's why it's displaying the id only , you should make the `imran-Production Manager` inside you `sql` select as alias and then give that alias as a second parameter

Comment: Ok ill give it a try and get back to you